# Hide part of the text returned from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage I want to hide part of the text in an object returned by the server.for example:

```
<div>
    <h4>{{name.SubName}}</h4>
</div>
```

The string returned by {{name.SubName}} contains a name followed by some text within brackets, like this "Sample Name(XYZ)". I want to be able to hide anything that is appearing within brackets i.e. (XYZ) in this case.
Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: hide or u want to only show name ?

Comment: Are you using Angular or something similar to render what's in the brackets?

Comment: @Sebastian No I am not using angular- using mustache templates

Comment: @PrototypeChain only want to show the part of the name that is outside the brakcet i.e. Sample Name in this case

Comment: @Anurag use Functions -> https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon returning from server, add a function to the object that returns intended format, like

```
$.get('example', function(name){
    name.cleanSubName = function(){
        this.SubName.replace(/\([^)]+\)/, "")
    }
});
```

and use it in the template like,

```
<h4>{{name.cleanSubName()}}</h4>
```

regex borrowed from @Rohan Kumar :)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to don't respond the name having `()` from server and if there are `()` then you can replace it at server side(if the full name is not in use at client side).

In **PHP** you can use the [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like,

```
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","","Sample Name(XYZ)"); // 'Sample Name'
```

And in **Javascript** you can use,

```
"Sample Name(XYZ)".replace(/\([^)]+\)/,""); // you need to use name instead of string
```